# How to convert a number of spaces(if more than one) to single dash using PHP

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace, preg-match

I can convert Space to dash.

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
```

But I want to convert a number of spaces; two, three, four, five, six or soon.. spaces into single dash

into `-`

Comment: there is no earlier contribution answering it already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ***regex*** using `preg_replace`

```
$string = preg_replace( '!\s+!', '-', $string );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 preg_replace('/\/s+/g', '-', $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `preg_replace()`:

```
preg_replace('/[[:space:]]+/', '-', $string);
```